# Does statsmodels OLS normalise variables?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

does `statsmodels.api.OLS` first normalise variables such that if my design matrix contains variables of very different magnitudes then this would help (X'X)**(-1) to not be ill conditioned?

Comment: No, statsmodels takes the X matrix as provided by user. Using formulas allows to specify preprocessing of data for design matrix.